# can't access my lan's webserver after reconfiguring the lan

Tags: networking, router, lan, webserver

I recently changed isp and got a cable modem which works fine for most things but I put it on bridge mode to add the modem router I was using with my previous isp as it has more features I like to use, and after configuring it as router only, I can't access my lan's web server anymore... my knowledge is limited, as configuring both modems was difficult for me, now I don't know whats wrong as everything is fine but not the web sever, which is working, as I can access it locally. Does anybody knows whats wrong?

Well the solution was to open ports 80 and 25 in windows' firewall. It may sound silly but as I didnt have to mess with the firewall before, I thought it was a problem with the router configuration.

Comment: Did you open ports across the modems? That way you can access your lan webserver?

Comment: Im sorry to admit I don't know what are you talking about, and even when most things are working, Im not sure if I did things right

Comment: Could you post your models you are working with? along with some info on your lan server say ip address and maybe some fake names or numbers for the scenario.

Comment: the modem is a TG862a, the router is an Archer D7... theTG uses the local ip 192.168.0.1, so I changed the ip of the router to 192.168.0.2 (it was 192.168.1.1), I configured the router with the settings from the TG: internet ip, subnet mask, default gateway and dns', connected the cable via ethernet to the wan connector of the router. the lan part was harder because I had to guess the default gateway, so I just picked a different 1 till it worked, turned DHCP on and then I got internet on all the computers and mobile devices.

Comment: I didn't have enough space to type... All I did was after checking tutorials from internet; the bridge part was easy, configuring the router not... I have being trying to forward port 80 but still doesn't work; the page times out and a program to check the ports still reports the 80 being closed.

Comment: @Horacius Please [edit] and add the additional information to the question (not in the comments)

Comment: SOLVED. I had to open the 80 port in my server's firewall... I don't know why as it used to work before reconfiguring the network

Comment: You might want to post that as an answer, maybe in a little more detail.